# Scripting Xcode

Tags: xcode, shell, scripting, xcode4

Does Xcode support any kind of built-in scripting? I am looking to automate the branding of a base app (creating a new target, adding files to the target, setting target properties) so that it can be executed by a script.

The project currently uses AppleScript to automate (most of) the process, but in practice it seems very flaky and unreliable as it is literally scripting key presses and user-interface interaction. Is there a better way to programmatically interact with Xcode, or its project files?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Apple Script dictionary provided by Xcode.

1. Open AppleScript Editor.
2. Choose "Open Dictionary..."
3. Find and select Xcode

You will see something like this:

[image]

So there are lots of structured APIs for you to manipulate. Happy coding!

Xcode Project Suite looks particularly promising... If Xcode 4 does not implement these methods, maybe you want to go back to Xcode 3? But most likely that is not an option.

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the Xcode 4's AppleScript API is documented, but not implemented...

Comment: and if something is documented but not implemented, file a bug with Apple ( via http://bugreporter.apple.com ).  The more developers who complain, the more likely it is Apple will devote resources to fixing their developer tools to work as they're *supposed to*.